# Use of varargs into java method called by Matlab

Tags: java, eclipse, matlab, rest, variadic-functions

I created a jar file by eclipse and in this file there is a class with this method

```
public Response getJsonFromRest(String urlstr, String... queryParams)
```

my target it is to return an object with a result of Rest call based on urlstr param. To create a generic method I used String... queryParams so I can use this method irrispective of number of query params. When I call this method in eclipse i can use 0,1 or a lot of query param, but when I call this method from matlab I have to set two param for getJsonFromRest, one for urlstr e one query param.
Why isn't possible to use varargs in matlab?

This is the codes

```
public Response getJsonFromRest(String urlstr, String... queryParams)  {
        URL url;
        try {
            //check if there are query params.
            if (queryParams.length==0)
                url = new URL(urlstr);
            else
                url = new URL(addQueryParam(urlstr, queryParams));

            HttpURLConnection conn =
                    (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                return new Response(conn.getResponseCode(), conn.getResponseMessage());
            }

            // Buffer the result into a string
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            rd.close();

            conn.disconnect();

            return new Response(conn.getResponseCode(), sb.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //417 for exception
            return new Response(417, e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    private String addQueryParam(String urlstr, String... queryParams){
        String symbol="?";
        String newUrl=urlstr;
        for (String param:queryParams){
            newUrl+=symbol+param;
            symbol="&";
        }
        System.out.println(newUrl);
        return newUrl;
    }
```

Comment: In Java, this actually compiles to a method with two parameters, one `String` and one `String[]`. Is it possible that Matlab is seeing the second parameter as an array? Can you pass an array as the second parameter from Matlab and see what happens?

Comment: perfect, it works using {''} for no query param and ['name=Hello','surname=World'} for several param.
I post above my code if someone needs

Comment: I finally got back here and posted it as an answer (I had only put it in a comment before because I don't have Matlab, so until you replied I wasn't sure if my suggestion was correct).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a Java method that takes varargs parameters with an ellipsis (`...`) such as:

```
public Response getJsonFromRest(String urlstr, String... queryParams)
```

Java actually generates a method that takes an array for the varargs, like this:

```
public Response getJsonFromRest(String urlstr, String[] queryParams)
```

When you call this method from Java with multiple parameters, an array is automatically created for you and passed as the second parameter, but Matlab doesn't understand that. You will have to explicitly create an array with your parameters in Matlab and pass it as the second parameter to the Java method.